# Check if user exist in oracle database windows forms (C#)?

Tags: c#, oracle11g, windows-forms-designer

thanks everyone!
I tried to do it by creating this method ,but its not working 

        *private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {*

```
        string oradb = "Data Source=ORCL;User Id=ADMIN;Password=123;";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_USER WHERE USER_ID=" + textBox1.Text + " AND PASS=" + textBox2.Text + ";";
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {

            if (!reader.Read())
            { MessageBox.Show("User Name Not Found"); }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
 }
```

Erro:ORA-00911:INVALID CHARACTER ??

who can help me fix my problem?? THANKS YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: You need to explain what "not working" means.

Comment: Erro:ORA-00911:INVALID CHARACTER ??

Comment: You also should never paste together strings like that; use SQL prepared statements instead. What the value in the text box? The error message seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_USER WHERE USER_ID="+textBox1.Text+" AND PASS="+textBox2.Text";
bool exists = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

if(exists)
{
   MessageBox.Show("LOGIN SUCCESS");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("LOGIN NOT SUCCESS");
}
```

Note, that you must use parameters instead concatenation to avoid SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute command like

```
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

or

```
cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

In Your code I cannot see where and how are you executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
     try
    {
        conn.Open();
       OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (!reader.Read())
        { MessageBox.Show("User Name Not Found"); }

        if (!password.Equals(reader["password"].ToString())) 
        {
             status=true;
             MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password");

        }
        else {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Success");
             }

    }catch(Exception ex) 
      { 
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         status=false;
      }
```

Comment: thank you very much, but my problem isn't solved